# How to resize an image inside a frame?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, transform

[image]

How can I edit this image to make the image of the woman square-shaped and the polaroid frame around it resized to fit it?  It's not necessary that the photo is rotated, but ok to be rotated.

The edge and shadow should still be visible.

Comment: if you do that, it will deform the aspect ratio of the photo. Unless you edit the photo and the frame separately. Is that what you want? do you want the frame to stay the same size or should it shrink to match the photo? Should the frame also be square?

Comment: Should the polaroid still be rotated? Should the edge and shadow of the polaroid still be visible?

Comment: you have triad to ask the same again. Seemingly you know nothing of Photoshop's layers and editing functionality. Select with polygonal lasso the top 2/3 of your photo, cut and paste it to a new layer. Move it to its wanted place. See it in ultra low resolution here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubmakt49euiidq9/Squared_Polaroid.psd?dl=0  Redo  in high enough resolution. Fix small defects at the seams by cloning or painting manually something to a new layer.

Answer (score 3):

- Select the *Crop Tool*.
- Rotate the image by dragging outside the frame.
- Set the image ratio to *1 : 1 (Square)*.
- Position and scale the frame to the desired crop.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the crop.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! And sorry I wasn't being clear - I meant that I'd want the woman image to be square shaped BUT still keep the polaroid frame around it.  Would you know how to achieve that?

Comment: @user2277916 - you need to clarify your question.  Do you want the frame to also be resized so the square image fits it, should it be rotated the same as the original?  This question needs more detail if you want a proper answer.